# Why is the thread status dead?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, winapi, sleep, getmessage

That is the question. I called a function using a thread, but when I return to main control, main becomes in sleep status within a few moments.

Example (`Look` here is a line that calls a Win32API function `GetMessage`):

```
Start()
e = Thread.new { Look() }
for _i in 0..1000
    puts e.status
end
```

This code should print the `e`'s status 1000 times, but it just prints once. I cannot find a reasonable error. `Look` does not return until it gets a message, so I suspect that this could be causing an error.

Comment: you'd better show us the code of `Look`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the status of `e` is `nil`, which `puts` displays as an empty string.

A `nil` status means the thread terminated abnormally.

Whatever is wrong, your code is printing *something* 1000 times, and you should put some visible text in the `puts` to show that.

Also, rather than use a throw-away variable `_i`, write

```
1000.times do
    puts e.status
end
```

Comment: It seems to me `puts` will display `nil` in console instead of an empty string

Comment: @BobCromwell: `puts nil.to_s.inspect` produces `""`

Comment: you are right about your statement however `puts nil` produces `nil`.

Comment: `puts nil` prints an empty line and returns `nil` (`puts` always returns `nil`).

Comment: I am sorry to have used *produces*. @BobCromwell please try `puts nil` and see what you get.

Comment: I am using Ruby 1.8.7 on Mac Mountain Lion, I do get following result: `nil ==> nil` with `puts nil` in `irb`. I am open to I am totally wrong .By the way, I raise an exception in the `Thread.new {}` block and it prints 1000 nil in console.

Answer (score 0):

I solved thanks for all your help,
the error was in that i only need to change GetMessageA for PeekMessage
so thread doesn't interpret that is dead jeje

Some.Proxy